# How to read/write the file in internel storage by default in android

Tags: android

In my app i want to read the file from internel storage by default without looking into externel SD location.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try openFileInput() method that will look into internel storage

```
          FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("file_name",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
           fOut.write(data.getBytes());
           fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always put your file in the assets folder. And then access it like this

```
           String mCSVfile = "Import_Functions.csv";
            AssetManager manager = myContext.getAssets();
            InputStream inStream = null;
            inStream = manager.open(mCSVfile);

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inStream));
```

This is for reading the file.

Hope it helps :)